# Import CSV to Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, csv

I am working on a Django based web application.

I am going to import a csv to postgresql database, which has over 100,000 lines, and use it as a database for the Django application.
Here, I've faced two problems.
The field name includes special characters like this:

```
%oil, %gas, up/down, CAPEX/Cash-flow, D&C Cape,...
```

1st, How should I define the field name of Postgresql database to import csv?

2nd, After import, I am going to get data through django model. Then how can I define the Django model variable name that includes special characters?

Of course, It's possible if I change the column name of the csv which includes special characters, but I don't want to change it. I want to import original csv without any changes.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If you use `copy` then you don't even need to specify column names, provided the content lines up identically.

Comment: Thanks.@Hambone. But I don't think it's correct soluction.

Comment: You should at least try @Hambone's suggestion, before you disqualify it. His suggestion is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special characters in your example. At least not any that would be problematic from the python or database point of view.

First of, avoid dubious field names, especially in finance. `%oil` can mean either oil share, oil margin or something else. Define a model with meaningful names like

```
class FinancialPeformanceData(models.Model):

     oil_share = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
     gas_share = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
     growth = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
     capex_to_cf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
     ... etc.
```

Then you use `copy` to import data from CSV as @Hambone suggested. You don't need headers in CSV files.

```
def import_csv(request):

    file = './path/to/file'
    with open(file, 'rb') as csvfile:
          with closing(connections['database_name_from_settings'].cursor()) as cursor:
                cursor.copy_from(
                    file=csvfile,
                    table='yourapp_financialperformancedata', #<-- table name from db
                    sep='|',  #<-- delimiter
                    columns=(
                        'oil_share',
                        'gas_share',
                        'growth',
                        'capex_to_cf',
                        ... etc.
                    ),
            )

    return HttpResponse('Done!')
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. This helped me out.

Comment: You probably won't get it working the first time, but stick with it. It can be done. And my example won't work if you have headers in CSV. I'm importing CSVs with millions of rows this way.

Comment: Thanks. At first i thought header is parsed, too. That's why I think parsing is problematic and declined @hambone's one.